# Which GUI framework/component should I use. I am using Spring MVC with Java and intend to create web applications

Tags: spring-mvc

Which GUI framework/component should I use. I am using Spring MVC with Java and intend to create web applications

I was looking for something similar to primefaces. But it seems that primefaces only works with spring web flow. I believe only a certain category of applications can be created with spring web flow which could be a negative point for using primefaces with spring.

I could use jquery but the jquery is not as good as primefaces when it comes to quickly creating web pages...

Thanks for the help guys..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have look at Thymeleaf [ http://www.thymeleaf.org ] as a template engine, combined with either mere jQuery or (as you say you consider it a bit too simple) jQuery + backbone.js (which is a javascript MVC framework) [ 
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ ]

The client side would be well covered with these two js libs, and thymeleaf's javascript inlining capabilities would ease integration a bit...